# How to set a div as background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found something interesting on this link. But I can't figure out how to make it and I want to know if anyone has any idea how. So what I realised on this is that even if you resize de browser window the elements keep floating but somehow the only focused element here is the webpage not the floating divs from left and right. This is what I've tried https://jsfiddle.net/eoopvgmc/9/ but the only thing that is working is those floating elements.

Here is what I want to know how to do it http://demo.inskinmedia.com/cds/show.php?live=uxtxbpwvx&ismState=1

```
(function($) {
            var element = $('.left-zone'),
                originalY = element.offset().top;
            var topMargin = 0;
            element.css('position', 'relative');
            $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                element.stop(false, false).animate({
                    top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

        (function($) {
            var element = $('.right-zone'),
                originalY = element.offset().top;
            var topMargin = 0;
            element.css('position', 'relative');
            $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                element.stop(false, false).animate({
                    top: scrollTop < -250 ? -250 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Looks like position: fixed to me. Unless you insist on the annoying scroll effect.

Comment: But if is position fixed, it should stop on the left floating div when you resize the window. Am I right?

Comment: I don't see the desired page doing any special at all? It appears to have a fixed width on the elements resulting in no resize or change of float with the browser at all?

Comment: Is not about to resize the elements. Is about how when I drag the window from one side is not stopping in the left div and that is going somehow under the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a div with a fixed width to wrap them

Edit: Changed the code to fit the request ->

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.ads').css({
      'top': $(window).scrollTop() + 'px'
    });
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main_content {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.top_banner {
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
}
.left-zone,
.right-zone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 224px;
  height: 284px;
  transition: top 0.8s;
}
.left-zone {
  background: yellow;
  left: -224px;
}
.right-zone {
  background: red;
  right: -224px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-zone ads"></div>
  <div class="top_banner"></div>
  <div class="main_content"></div>
  <div class="right-zone ads"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not this what I want. When I resize the browser the yellow block should go inside the window. have a look on that link when you resize from left or right

Comment: All right, so you have to use a wrapper AND position absolute. I will do it a codepen and edit my answer after I finished.

Comment: Here it is : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/KpRyRN (I edit the snippet in the answer as well)

Comment: can you make it start when the "ads" reach top? https://jsfiddle.net/eoopvgmc/13/

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I tried to reproduce the behavior of your link here (updated codepen: http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/KpRyRN).

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = $('.ads').offset().top, top;
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset + 'px';
        $('.ads').css({
            'top': top
        });
    })
});` is something like this but I want to start when blue panel reach the top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82947/discussion-between-markus-hayner-and-mehdi-brillaud).